# Store a string of values to list of values?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I currently looking for an easy way to convert a string with Comma seperated values example `"[2323,1231.1,123123.2 ,21 ... ,2131]"` to a list of values, or a numpy.array of the value.  I want it to be done as efficient as possible, is there a python command that can do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) can do it:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("[2323,1231.1,123123.2 ,21 ,2131]")
[2323, 1231.1, 123123.2, 21, 2131]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string_list = '[2323, 2324,2325,2326]'
list_numbers = json.loads(string_list)
```

simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

The `ast` that @wim suggest is probably the best choice; but there are some alternatives:

```
In [2036]: txt="[2323,1231.1,123123.2 ,21 ,2131]"
```

ast

```
In [2038]: ast.literal_eval(txt)
Out[2038]: [2323, 1231.1, 123123.2, 21, 2131]
```

json

```
In [2039]: import json
In [2040]: json.loads(txt)
Out[2040]: [2323, 1231.1, 123123.2, 21, 2131]
```

direct

```
In [2045]: [float(i) for i in txt[1:-1].split(',')]
Out[2045]: [2323.0, 1231.1, 123123.2, 21.0, 2131.0]
```

times:

```
In [2043]: timeit ast.literal_eval(txt)
10000 loops, best of 3: 37.7 µs per loop
In [2044]: timeit json.loads(txt)
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.57 µs per loop
In [2046]: timeit [float(i) for i in txt[1:-1].split(',')]
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.02 µs per loop
```

With different texts relative timings could be different; the ability to handle deviations from the strict list display could differ.

For convenience and immitating MATLAB `np.matrix` can also parse a string; but the result is 2d and slower

```
In [2047]: np.matrix(txt)
Out[2047]: 
matrix([[  2.32300000e+03,   1.23110000e+03,   1.23123200e+05,
           2.10000000e+01,   2.13100000e+03]])
In [2048]: timeit np.matrix(txt)
10000 loops, best of 3: 184 µs per loop
```

`np.array` can also handle a list of strings:

```
In [2050]: np.array( txt[1:-1].split(','),float)
Out[2050]: 
array([  2.32300000e+03,   1.23110000e+03,   1.23123200e+05,
         2.10000000e+01,   2.13100000e+03])
In [2051]: timeit np.array( txt[1:-1].split(','),float)
...
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.03 µs per loop
```